# Libgdx - Actor's position is incorrect

Tags: java, math, input, drag-and-drop, libgdx

I'm pulling my hair out. I've spent a few hours now on this. Here is what I am doing. I have an image that is an actor. I can move this image to wherever I want. That works fine. I added a Slider so I can also resize this image. This is where the problem sets in. Once I resize it, I can still move it, but it is no longer where my finger is. It is, if it shrunk in size, to the NE. If it increased, it is to the SE. (of my finger). Anyways, I have no idea what is causing this. I spent an hour just writing different equations for adjusting per size, but nothing is working. Also, the world bounds become incorrect too. I shouldn't be allowed to move the actor/image outside of the screen. I do a simple check. (actor.getX() <= 0). I feel like I should note that before resizing, everything works fine. Anyways, the bounds check was simple, right? Well, if I make my image smaller, it gets stopped before it reaches the edge. If I make it larger, it can enter the edge a bit. The same for the opposite side, except that this time if its larger, it gets stopped before it reaches, and if its smaller, it can go in a bit. Here, let me show you some code...

My Table for the Slider:

```
private Table buildSlidersLayer() {
        Table layer = new Table();
        layer.right().top();
        Label label = new Label("A Button Size", skinLibgdx);
        layer.add(label);
        layer.row();
        sldSize = new Slider(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.01f, false, skinLibgdx);
        layer.add(sldSize);
        sldSize.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                sldSizeVal = sldSize.getValue();
                divFacAButton = ((((1.0f - sldSizeVal) - 0.01f) * (2.0f - 0.7f)) / (0.99f - 0.01f)) + 0.7f;
                aButton.setSize(120 / divFacAButton, 120 / divFacAButton);
            }

        });
        // sldSize.setPosition(60, 60);
        return layer;
    }
```

My divFacAButton is between a range of 0.7 and 2.0(aprrox.). I divide 120 by these to get the size.

Now, this is how I move my image:

```
aButton = new Image(skinCydeonWorld, "a-button");
        layer.addActor(aButton);
        aButton.setSize(aButton.getWidth() / 1.5f,
                aButton.getHeight() / 1.5f);
        aButton.setOrigin(aButton.getWidth() / 2, aButton.getHeight() / 2);
        aButton.setPosition(GamePreferences.instance.aButtonX,
                GamePreferences.instance.aButtonY);
        aButton.setRotation(180f);

        aButton.addListener(new DragListener() {

            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer) {
                float xAspect = stage.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
                float yAspect = stage.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
                aButton.setPosition(
                        (Gdx.input.getX() - aButton.getHeight() / 2f) * xAspect,
                        ((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) - aButton
                                .getHeight() / 2f) * yAspect);
                checkAndAdjustPos(aButton);
                super.touchDragged(event, x, y, pointer);
            }

        });
```

Here I move the image. I set the image position to wherever I clicked, minus half the width on the x, and half the height on the y.

Here's an illustration on how the positioning is off, as well as it being stopped too early from the wall:
[image]

And so that's basically it. After resizing, the bounds and positions seem to get out-of-whack. I'm totally lost and have a major headache. If anybody has any idea why this is happening, what I'm doing wrong, or how I can fix this, I would be eternally(ok, maybe not) grateful. :) 








I found a solution with the help of BrainfoG313!
Here's my new code:

```
aButton.addListener(new DragListener() {

            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer) {
                xAspect = Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH / Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    yAspect = Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT/ Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
                aButton.setPosition(
                        (Gdx.input.getX() - (aButton.getWidth() * divFacAButton / 2f))
                                * xAspect,
                        ((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) - (aButton
                                .getHeight() * (divFacAButton < 1.3f ? 0f : divFacAButton) / 2f))
                                * yAspect);
                checkAndAdjustPos(aButton);
                super.touchDragged(event, x, y, pointer);
            }

        });
```

Checking if the actor leaves the screen:

```
{
        if (actor.getX() - (aButton.getWidth() / 2 / divFacAButton) + 80f / 2f < 0)
            actor.setPosition(
                    (aButton.getWidth() / 2 / divFacAButton) - 80f / 2f,
                    actor.getY());
        if (actor.getX() + actor.getWidth()
                / (minSize + maxSize - divFacAButton) > stage.getWidth() * xAspect)
            actor.setPosition(stage.getWidth() * xAspect - actor.getWidth()
                    / (maxSize + minSize - divFacAButton), actor.getY());
        if (actor.getY() - (aButton.getHeight() / 2 / divFacAButton) + 80f / 2f < 0)
            actor.setPosition(actor.getX(),
                    (aButton.getWidth() / 2 / divFacAButton) - 80f / 2f);
        if (actor.getY() + actor.getHeight()
                / (minSize + maxSize - divFacAButton)/* / divFactor */> maxHeight * yAspect)
            actor.setPosition(actor.getX(), maxHeight * yAspect - actor.getHeight()
                    / (minSize + maxSize - divFacAButton));
    }
```

For checking if it left outside of the screen, I used two different formulas/equations:

For the x-axis:

> ```
> xPosition - (1/2currentWidth / divFacAButton) + 1/2defaultWidth = leftEdge
> ```

For the y-axis:

> ```
> yPosition - (1/2currentHeight / divFacAButton) + 1/2defaultHeight = bottomEdge
> ```

And my second formula/equation:

For the x-axis

> xPosition + currentWidth / (minSize + maxSize - divFacAButton) = rightEdge

For the y-axis

> yPosition + currentHeight / (minSize + maxSize - divFacAButton) = topEdge

It's not perfect, but it's pretty close and works fine! :D

Comment: not sure but i remember something that the drag image has an ofset so you can see it if you touch drag it with the finger on an tablet. But i don't know if you can change it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just breezin' through your code, it looks like the resizing slider is adjusting the image size and not the container. I ran into a similar situation when I was working with Circles and drawing images over them; the hitbox and image wouldn't align. Horrible picture, incoming!
[image: Enlarging images and not the containers!]

float xAspect = stage.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

float yAspect = stage.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

This is the point in your code that makes me wonder.

Comment: Yup! That's exactly how it is! So the virtual box around it isn't changing which is causing the issues? It still is applying the box for the original size then?

Comment: Check my edit! See if changing the xAspect and yAspect to thebutton.getWidth rather than the stage.getWidth, or figure out a method to resize both the image AND the container.

Comment: Alright. I'll do it once I get home and ret you know how it works. The x/yAspect is so no matter the screen size, the point will properly be converted per screen res. Should I make another x/yAspect for the button too?

Comment: Tried swapping the stage w/h for the button's, didn't work. :/

Comment: Here's what I believe is happening. You were correct in your first comment; the image within the 'box' (stage) is resizing but because the stage itself is not changing, it is drawing the image from that set stage size, causing this issue. In the image I posted, the image is using the top-right corner as a reference point for resizing. If you wanted it to resize properly, you need to apply the changes to the stage AND the image at the same time. Using float xAspect = stage.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); will return the same exact box size because the stage is never changing. Make sense?

Comment: One thing to try is in your 'changed' method, adjust the stage's w/h by the divFacAButton as well.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help! I used what you said, along with my own calculations, to create a formula that, albeit not perfect, works good enough. I'll update the OP with the new methods! Thanks!